# hibernate - how to set auto increment in both mysql and oracle databases?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate, auto-increment

I'm using hibernate with a MySQL database in my spring MVC project. I have used the `@GeneratedValue` annotation to set auto-incremenet on my id fields. So all my entities have this piece of code and everything is working as expected:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

At this time, I want to switch to an Oracle database. Now, I have two questions here:

**1.** What's the best solution to set auto-increment field in oracle? I used this code, but is not working:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_Sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name="id_Sequence", allocationSize=1)
```

**2(More important question).** Is there any way to use **a unique annotation to set auto-increment that will work for both MySQL and Oracle**?

Answer (score 0):

**1:** 
If you define your own generator, your have to use the generator attribute in `@GeneratedValue`. And if you have created your own sequence you have to define the name with `sequenceName` otherwise hibernate will create one for you.

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="some_gen", sequenceName="Emp_Seq")
@GeneratedValue(generator="some_gen")
```

**2:**
The most flexible (and portable) way is to use the `TABLE` strategy

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
```

or more explicit

```
@GeneratedValue(generator="some_gen")
@TableGenerator(name="some_gen",
    table="ID_GEN",
    pkColumnName="GEN_NAME",
    valueColumnName="GEN_VAL")
```

This will generate (if schema generation is enabled) a table `ID_GEN` with the columns `GEN_NAME`, `GEN_VALUE`, if schema generation is not available you have to create this table on your own.

You find more complete information from hibernate docs here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No need to use `strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE` in your first suggestion?

Comment: I don't think because you defined your generator to be a a `@SequenceGenerator`.

Comment: I put `@SequenceGenerator(name="some_gen", sequenceName="Emp_Seq")
@GeneratedValue(generator="some_gen")` above my id, but not working. Also `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)` does not work.

Comment: Is hibernate able to create your sequence (or a table) on your database, is schema generation enabled. Try to create the sequence on your own and name it with `sequenceName`.

Comment: What do you mean **Is hibernate able to create your sequence**? What I need to do to make hibernate enable to create sequence? Could you explain me further?

Comment: A sequence in Oracle is a database object and has to be created like a table. I don't know if you created your tables on your own, if so you have to create the sequence on your database with `CREATE SEQUENCE Emp_Seq;`. If hibernate created all your tables (this is called schema generation), then hibernate must have all required privileges on your database to do so.